# Check the item in ToolStripMenuItem dynamically through Sub Function

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am new to .Net Visual Basic, I am currently self learning and trying to make some small application.

I need a help on Checking a sub menu item of `ToolStripMenuItem`

Complete concept is like:

I have a datagridview in which user will be able to rearrange the column or make a column visible or Hidded for this I have Sub / Function like below:

```
Public Sub Fun_Grid_Colomn_Visibility(ByVal GridName As DataGridView, ByRef ColName As String, ByVal MS_col As ToolStripMenuItem, ChkVal As Boolean)
        If ChkVal = True Then
            With GridName
                .Columns("" & ColName & "").Visible = False
            End With
            MS_col.Checked = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If ChkVal = False Then
            GridName.Columns("" & ColName & "").Visible = True
            MS_col.Checked = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

On the form close I will be saving the user grid format as below (Got code from another Q/A Post) :

```
Public Sub WriteGrideViewSetting(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal FileName As String)
        Dim settingwriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\temp\" & FileName & ".xml", Nothing)
        settingwriter.WriteStartDocument()
        settingwriter.WriteStartElement(dgv.Name)
        Dim count As Integer = dgv.Columns.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            settingwriter.WriteStartElement("column")
            settingwriter.WriteStartElement("Name")
            settingwriter.WriteString(dgv.Columns(i).Name)
            settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
            settingwriter.WriteStartElement("width")
            settingwriter.WriteString(dgv.Columns(i).Width.ToString())
            settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
            settingwriter.WriteStartElement("headertext")
            settingwriter.WriteString(dgv.Columns(i).HeaderText)
            settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
            settingwriter.WriteStartElement("displayindex")
            settingwriter.WriteString(dgv.Columns(i).DisplayIndex.ToString())
            settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
            settingwriter.WriteStartElement("visible")
            settingwriter.WriteString(dgv.Columns(i).Visible.ToString())
            settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
            settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
        Next

        settingwriter.WriteEndElement()
        settingwriter.WriteEndDocument()
        settingwriter.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

If the user is reopening the form I used the below (Q/A code) to rearrange Datagridview column as pervious :

```
Public Sub ReadDataGridViewSetting(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal FileName As String, ByRef Frm_name As Form)


        Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList

        Dim CMSN_ToolName As String
        Dim Var_file_Chk As String = "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\temp\" & FileName & ".xml"

        If System.IO.File.Exists(Var_file_Chk) = True Then
            Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Var_file_Chk, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            xmldoc.Load(fs)
            xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("column")

            For i As Integer = 0 To xmlnode.Count - 1
                Dim columnName As String = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
                Dim width As Integer = Integer.Parse(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim())
                Dim headertext As String = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim()
                Dim displayindex As Integer = Integer.Parse(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.Trim())
                Dim visible As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(4).InnerText.Trim())
                dgv.Columns(columnName).Width = width
                dgv.Columns(columnName).HeaderText = headertext
                dgv.Columns(columnName).DisplayIndex = displayindex
                dgv.Columns(columnName).Visible = visible
            Next
            fs.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now what I need is that a Function or Sub for the Itemmenu. If a Particular column is Visible in the datagridview then the particular Itemmenu should be checked else it would be unchecked. I need this function when Itemmenu is being displayed / opened.

what I tried just (for sample) in Itemmenu opening is like

```
Private Sub ColumnsToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ColumnsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownOpening

        If DGV_CompList.Columns("DGC_Est").Visible = True Then

        Dim CMSN_ToolName = MS_CV_Est.Name

        Dim unused As ToolStripMenuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem(CMSN_ToolName) With {
         .Checked = True
          }

        End If
    End Sub
```

1. DGV_CompList -> DataGridView
2. DGC_Est -> Column Name of datagridview
3. MS_CV_Est ->  - ToolStripMenuItem which need to checked
   (Note: I will be changing the MenuItem Name to Match Datagrid Column name for Sync)

But the ToolStripMenuItem is not getting checked.

Actually I need function / Sub where I will be able to pass the grid name and the Menuname and loop through the grid columns and check if the column is visible or not if the particular column is visible then I need to check that item in the itemmenu.

I am requesting for the sub / function because it can be used for any toolstripmenuitem in any form.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Since `MS_CV_Est` is a ToolStripMenuItem, why don't you just set `MS_CV_Est.Checked = true`?

Comment: @Jimi, Sorry if I missed any thing here. I need a common Sub / Function to check the submenu item. Process is like I will loop through datagridview columns, if a column is visible then I will make the menu as checked. To the Sub / Function I will be passing the DGV name and that would help for looping process. What I think is like we can reuse the same sub / function for any menuitem which are available in different forms.

Comment: Well, that's not clear at all in the code you posted. How do you associate a specific DataGridView Column to a specific ToolStripMenuItem? A menu item that belongs to what top level parent object?

Comment: @Jimi, I have updated the Question. Can you please check now and see is request is clear. Thanks!! Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: There's no answer to either question I asked, read again my previous comment. It's about the tools you're using. E.g., have you associated a ContextMenuStrip to those Columns? When/how are these menu items built? Do you know how databinding works (how to bind the properties of two objects)? Or, do you know how to use the Tag property of UI objects?

Comment: @Jimi, 1. have you associated a ContextMenuStrip to those Columns?  - No! 2. When/how are these menu items built? - I used UI design to build the menus. Do you know how databinding works (how to bind the properties of two objects)? Or, do you know how to use the Tag property of UI objects?- I don't have an idea on Tag property. I am really new to the VB .net coding Just with few knowledge on coding over VB 6 I am trying to self learn vb .net

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks!!!!!! :) for the hint you provided about Tag property, Just I learnt new thing today. I have assigned the Tag property with the column name for all the required MenuItem and created a Sub / Function (Edited the Question with Solution). Thank you so much

Comment: Well, I'm glad that the comment helped :) If you have a solution to the problem, post it as an answer: you can answer your own question. Then accept it as soon as it's  allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Jimi's hint, assigned each required Menuitem's Tag property with the datagridview column name and created the below sub / function :

```
 Public Sub Fun_ToolStripMenuItem_Check(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal TS_Menu_Items As ToolStripItemCollection)

        For Each item As ToolStripMenuItem In TS_Menu_Items.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
            If Not item.Tag = "" Then
                If dgv.Columns(item.Tag).Visible = True Then
                    item.Checked = True
                Else
                    item.Checked = False
                End If
            End If

            For Each submenu_item As ToolStripMenuItem In item.DropDownItems.OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem)
                If Not submenu_item.Tag = "" Then
                    If dgv.Columns(submenu_item.Tag).Visible = True Then
                        submenu_item.Checked = True
                    Else
                        submenu_item.Checked = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next

        Next
      End Sub
```

Note in the loop used - " OfType(Of ToolStripMenuItem) " because I have ToolStripSeparator between the Itemmenus.

On mouse over called the Sub by :

```
Private Sub MS_ColumnVisible_DropDownOpening(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MS_ColumnVisible.DropDownOpening
    Fun_ToolStripMenuItem_Check(DGV_CompList, MS_CompDGV.Items)
End Sub
```

'DGV_CompList' - Datagridview Name and 'MS_CompDGV' - ContextMenuStrip Name

More important is that I did not assign any value to the Tag property to Menuitems which are not used show or hide the datagridview columns.